# Ordenando uma lista de strings em python

Tags: python, python-2.7, classificação

Pessoal preciso ordenar uma lista que dentro dela há uma outra lista contendo exatamente uma string e um número, o problema é que não estou tendo o resultado desejado, vamos colocar um exemplo, se eu tiver a lista abaixo

```
a = [
    ['c2sp1s5', 0],
    ['c2sp1s10', 1],
    ['c2sp1s11', 0],
    ['c2sp1s1', 0]
]
```

e quero ela ordenada dessa maneira

```
a = [
    ['c2sp1s1', 0],
    ['c2sp1s5', 0],
    ['c2sp1s10', 1],
    ['c2sp1s11', 0]
]
```

Preciso que a lista seja ordenada como o exemplo acima, para que eu possa fazer uma comparação da lista resultante com uma outra lista que já está ordenada como a lista acima, assim extraindo o meu resultado desejado.
Porém se a minha lista estiver ordenada da maneira como segue o exemplo abaixo, terei um resultado incorreto.

Mais precisamente, preciso utilizar elas no mesmo formato, onde a string da lista interna esteja na mesma posição em ambas as listas, para que possa utilizar o mesmo dado da posição 1 da lista interna e extrair meu resultado.

Não consigo uma lista ordenada dessa maneira utilizando `sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0))`, pois eles me resultam em uma lista da seguinte maneira

```
a = [
    ['c2sp1s1', 0],
    ['c2sp1s10', 1],
    ['c2sp1s11', 0],
    ['c2sp1s5', 0]
]
```

Existe alguma maneira prática de fazer isso ou terei que implementar a ordenação na mão?

Comment: Ricardo, você não se atentou ao trecho que comentei sobre **todas as regras** para ordenação. Até então o resultado é, sim, o esperado, a menos que você explique detalhadamente o porque de não ser. As *strings* **sempre** começarão com `'c2sp1s'`? Se sim, a ordenação deverá ocorrer apenas considerando os últimos caracteres? Se não, quais são os possíveis valores? Por quê não define a lista com valores utilizando zeros a esquerda, tal como `'c2sp1s001'`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tentei detalhar o maximo possivel o motivo da ordenação não ser a desejada

Answer (score 3):

Como ainda não ficou perfeitamente claro na pergunta - e aparentemente o próprio autor não soube explicar - irei considerar para esta resposta *strings* independentes do formato com uma condição **bem especifica**: sempre que houver um valor inteiro na *string*, a classificação deverá considerar o valor numérico destes caracteres e não mais como texto; isto implicará, por exemplo, que a *string* `c2sp1s5` deverá aparecer antes que a *string* `c10sp1s5`, devido a presença dos valores numéricos 2 e 10 na *string* e que, geralmente, 2 é menor que 10.

Para a implementação desta lógica, irei criar uma função chamada `magic`, que como o nome sugere, fará mágica com a classificação. A função irá receber uma *string* para então separá-la a cada valor numérico encontrado, gerando uma lista de *strings*, algumas com apenas texto, outras com valores numéricos; por exemplo, com a entrada `c2sp1s5` irá gerar a lista `['c', '2', 'sp', '1', 's', '5']`, já a entrada `c2sp1s10` irá gerar a lista `['c', '2', 'sp', '1', 's', '11']`. Se compararmos as duas listas geradas, teríamos o mesmo problema inicial: cada termo das listas seriam comparadas uma a uma e o resultado seria exatamente o mesmo, pois ainda `'11`' seria menor que `'2'`, então, antes de compararmos a lista, devemos converter os valores numéricos para inteiros, resultando nas listas `['c', 2, 'sp', 1, 's', 5]` e `['c', 2, 'sp', 1, 's', 11]`; desta forma, ao se comparar as listas, no último termo seria comparado os valores inteiros 2 e 11, retornando 2 como menor que 11.

O código ficaria assim:

```
def magic(value):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d+)', value)
    return [int(part) if part.isdigit() else part for part in parts]
```

A primeira linha da função divide a entrada nos valores numéricos e a segunda retorna uma lista convertendo os valores numéricos em inteiros. Como a função espera apenas uma *string*, para utilizar no exemplo dado na pergunta, é necessário informar qual será a *string* que será considerada na classificação da lista. Neste caso, é a *string* presente no índice 0, então fazemos:

```
import re


def magic(value):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d+)', value)
    return [int(part) if part.isdigit() else part for part in parts]


a = [
    ['c2sp1s5', 0],
    ['c2sp1s10', 1],
    ['c2sp1s11', 0],
    ['c2sp1s1', 0]
]

print( sorted(a, key=lambda v: magic(v[0])) )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ocJhMA) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BraveUselessGardensnake)</sup>

O que gera o resultado>

```
[
    ['c2sp1s1', 0], 
    ['c2sp1s5', 0], 
    ['c2sp1s10', 1], 
    ['c2sp1s11', 0]
]
```